# Given a closed function f(x) with dom f open, if f converges to infinity as x converging to bd domf, does its L2-norm of gradient go to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-optimization

I am working on Exercise 10.7 on Page 558 of [B&V's Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/). Suppose that the function $f$ is closed. Show that the norm of the residual, $\|r(x,\nu)\|_2$, is closed and continuously
differentiable. I read the solution manual, in which its argument is confusing. Specifically, the domain of $\|r(x,\nu)\|_2$, $\operatorname{dom}f\times\mathbf{R}^p$, is open,

> Consider a sequence of points $(x^{(k)},\nu^{(k)})\in \operatorname{dom}\|r\|_2$ converging to a limit $(\bar{x},\bar{\nu})\in\operatorname{bd}\operatorname{dom}\|r\|_2$. Then $\bar{x}\in\operatorname{bd}\operatorname{dom}f$, and since $f$ is closed, $f(x^{(k)})\rightarrow\infty$, **hence** $\|\nabla f(x^{(k)})\|_2\rightarrow\infty$, and $\|r(x^{(k)},\nu^{(k)})\|_2\rightarrow\infty$.

My question is on the **''hence''**. Can we get the norm of its gradient converges to $\infty$ just from $f(x^{(k)})\rightarrow\infty$? My thinking is if $f(x)=x$, then $f'(x)\rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$, which contradicts the quoted argument. Can anyone help me understand the **''hence''**? Thanks.

Comment: There must be stronger assumptions on $f$. It should be differentiable for instance.

Comment: @daw Yes. I revised the question to include the assumption that $f$ is continuously
differentiable.